# Why does "thge" correct to "Chge" using spellcheck?

Tags: vimrc, spell-checking, spelling

I was showing a friend the spell-check feature in Vim which I add activated by adding the lines `setlocal spell` and `set spelllang=en_gb` to my `.vimrc`. He did the same on his end and tried a few spell corrections and found the following bizarre suggestion: `thge` (which he wrote to be a miss-spelling of "the") has the top suggestion of `chge` and the same is true on my end.

Why might this be? What on earth is this word? Is there a way of changing/removing this suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

chge is an abbreviation of "change."

If you do not like this word, just type `zw` to mark it as "wrong."

vim's spell word lists are obtained from free sources and are sometimes not ideal.  Fortunately, local custom word lists can be maintained with `zw` and `zg` (wrong and good respectively).